# Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refresh a function without refreshing the page but i'm getting this error.

HTML

```
<canvas id="js-chartjs-bars"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
  var 1 = "22";
  var 2 = "13";
  var 3 = "41";
  var 4 = "60";

  !function diagram() {
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const backgroundcolor = [];
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      if(data[i] <= 29) { backgroundcolor.push('rgba(194, 23, 0, 1)')}
      if(data[i] >= 30 && data[i] <= 54) { backgroundcolor.push('rgba(194, 149, 0, 1)')}
      if(data[i] >= 55) { backgroundcolor.push('rgba(10, 194, 0,1)')}
    }
    class t {
        static initChartsChartJS() {
            Chart.defaults.color = "#6a6f73", Chart.defaults.font.weight = "600", Chart.defaults.scale.grid.color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)", Chart.defaults.scale.grid.zeroLineColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)", Chart.defaults.scale.beginAtZero = !0, Chart.defaults.elements.line.borderWidth = 2, Chart.defaults.elements.point.radius = 4, Chart.defaults.elements.point.hoverRadius = 6, Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.radius = 3, Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.boxWidth = 15;
            let t, a, i = document.getElementById("js-chartjs-lines"),
                d = document.getElementById("js-chartjs-bars");
            i = {
                labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Charts",
                    fill: !0,
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundcolor
                },]
            }, null !== d && (a = new Chart(d, {
                type: "bar",
                data: i,
                options: {
                    responsive: !0,
                    maintainAspectRatio: !1,
                    plugins: {
                      datalabels: {
                        labels: {
                          title: {
                            color: 'white',
                            font:{
                              size: '18px'
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                },
                plugins: [
                  ChartDataLabels
                ]
                
            }))
        }
        static init() {
            this.initChartsChartJS()
        }
    }
    One.onLoad((() => t.init()));
    setInterval( diagram, 10000 );
  }();
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'js-chartjs-bars' can be reused
```

Is it possible to refresh the function itself without refreshing the page? or how I could handle it?

The Problem is what I found with google, i've to destroy the chart. When I try to destroy it, i do alway get, this is not defined.
I'm new to javascript, any advice would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to refresh the function that updates the chart without refreshing the page. The error message you're seeing indicates that you're trying to create a new chart on a canvas element where a chart already exists. To resolve this, you should destroy the existing chart before creating a new one.

Here's a revised approach that includes destroying the existing chart:

```js
// Assuming Chart.js v3 or newer
var chartInstance; // This will hold the instance of the chart.

function updateChart() {
  // Your data variables should be named properly; starting with a letter, $ or _
  var val1 = "22";
  var val2 = "13";
  var val3 = "41";
  var val4 = "60";
  
  const data = [val1, val2, val3, val4];
  const backgroundColor = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i] <= 29) { backgroundColor.push('rgba(194, 23, 0, 1)'); }
    else if(data[i] >= 30 && data[i] <= 54) { backgroundColor.push('rgba(194, 149, 0, 1)'); }
    else if(data[i] >= 55) { backgroundColor.push('rgba(10, 194, 0,1)'); }
  }

  // If a chart instance exists, destroy it before creating a new one
  if (chartInstance) {
    chartInstance.destroy();
  }

  const ctx = document.getElementById("js-chartjs-bars").getContext("2d");
  chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Charts",
        fill: true,
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          labels: {
            title: {
              color: 'white',
              font: {
                size: '18px'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
  });
}

// Initial call to set up the chart
updateChart();

// Set interval to update the chart every 10 seconds
setInterval(updateChart, 10000);
```

This script does the following:

- It defines a global variable `chartInstance` that holds the instance of the chart.
- The `updateChart` function checks if `chartInstance` is not `undefined`, which would mean a chart has already been created. If so, it destroys the existing chart instance with `chartInstance.destroy()`.
- It then creates a new chart as before.
- Instead of calling your diagram function immediately, we now call `updateChart` initially to set up the chart.
- We also call `updateChart` within `setInterval` to refresh the chart every 10 seconds.

Note that you need to ensure that the `ChartDataLabels` plugin and any necessary Chart.js libraries are correctly included in your page for this to work. Also, variable names in JavaScript cannot start with a digit; they should begin with a letter, an underscore (_), or a dollar sign ($). Therefore, I've renamed your variables `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, and `val4` accordingly.